# How is AM-GM supposed to be used to prove an inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I have recently started learning proofs involving inequalities and came across the AM-GM inequality, which seems like a quite powerful tool.
 However, I am not sure I understand how to use this tool properly, and I was wondering if there are acceptable strategies to be aware of when making use of the AM-GM inequality.

I have also tried solving an inequality involving AM-GM to learn how to use this tool as I go, but I'm not sure if what I've done so far is a valid approach.

> Here is the question:

Prove that if $x, y, z, w ≥ 0$,

 $\frac{x+y+z+w}{4} ≥ \sqrt[4]{xyzw}$

> Here is what I have done so far:

I noticed that $\sqrt[4]{xyzw}$ = $\sqrt{\sqrt{xy}\sqrt{zw}}$, and then used AM-GM, like so:

I let 
$a = \sqrt{xy}$ 
 $ b= \sqrt{zw}$

to make a use of $\frac{a+b}{2} ≥ \sqrt{ab}$. 

And, then, I subbed in the values:

$\frac{\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{zw}}{2} ≥ \sqrt{\sqrt{xy}\sqrt{zw}}$. 
Now I have a feeling I'm supposed to somehow make a use of the inequality ($\frac{a+b}{2} ≥ \sqrt{ab}$) once more, however, I am not exactly sure how I should go about doing it.

 **Any tips for a newbie like myself would be immensely helpful!** (Perhaps a link I can refer to, an article, etc)

 Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: What's wrong with using AM-GM on four numbers directly?

Comment: I just picked this inequality as a starting point to prove it using AM-GM for two variables first, and get exposed to the AM-GM inequality. I am eager to learn how to use this tool when dealing with inequalities requiring formal mathematical proofs.

Comment: Did you mean $\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{zw}$ where you wrote $\sqrt{zw}+\sqrt{zw}$?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry! Fixed.

Comment: This doesn't specifically pertain to the problem, but in general here are two sources that may help you: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean_Inequality https://brilliant.org/wiki/arithmetic-mean-geometric-mean/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with
$\dfrac{a+b}{2}
\ge \sqrt{ab}
$.
To prove this,
write it as
$\dfrac{a-2\sqrt{ab}+b}{2}
\ge 0
$,
and the left side is
$\dfrac{(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2}{2}
\ge 0
$.

Then,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{a+b+c+d}{4}
&=\dfrac{a+b}{4}+\dfrac{c+d}{4}\\
&=\dfrac{\dfrac{a+b}{2}}{2}+\dfrac{\dfrac{c+d}{2}}{2}\\
&\ge\dfrac{\sqrt{ab}}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{cd}}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{cd}}{2}\\
&\ge\sqrt{\sqrt{ab}\sqrt{cd}}\\
&=\sqrt{\sqrt{abcd}}\\
&=\sqrt[4]{abcd}\\
\end{array}
$

By induction on $n$,
with this technique
you can show that
$\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}a_k}{2^n}
\ge \sqrt[2^n]{\prod_{k=1}^n a_k}
$.

To show this is true
for any $m < 2^n$,
let
$a_j
=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^m a_k}{m}
$
for $j \gt m$
and see what happens.

As a matter of fact,
this was Cauchy's
original proof.

Here's the details (added later).

The left side is,
letting
$a = \dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^m a_k}{m}
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}a_k}{2^n}
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{m}a_k}{2^n}+\dfrac{\sum_{k=m+1}^{2^n}a_k}{2^n}\\
&=\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{m}a_k}{m}\dfrac{m}{2^n}+\dfrac{\sum_{k=m+1}^{2^n}a}{2^n}\\
&=\dfrac{am}{2^n}+\dfrac{(2^n-m)a}{2^n}\\
&=\dfrac{am}{2^n}+\dfrac{2^na}{2^n}-\dfrac{ma}{2^n}\\
&= a\\
&=\dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^ma_j}{m}\\
\end{array}
$

Similarly,
the right side is,
letting
$a_j
=b
=\left(\prod_{k=1}^{m} a_k\right)^{1/m}
$
for $j > m$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt[2^n]{\prod_{k=1}^{2^n} a_k}
&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^{2^n} a_k\right)^{1/2^n}\\
&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^{m} a_k\prod_{k=m+1}^{2^n} a_k\right)^{1/2^n}\\
&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^{m} a_k\right)^{1/2^n}\left(\prod_{k=m+1}^{2^n} a_k\right)^{1/2^n}\\
&=\left(b^m\right)^{1/2^n}\left(\prod_{k=m+1}^{2^n} b\right)^{1/2^n}\\
&=b^{m/2^n}\left(b^{2^n-m}\right)^{1/2^n}\\
&=b^{m/2^n}b^{(2^n-m)/2^n}\\
&=b\\
&=\left(\prod_{k=1}^{m} a_k\right)^{1/m}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$a \ge b$
or
$\dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^ma_j}{m}
\ge \left(\prod_{k=1}^{m} a_k\right)^{1/m}
$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x+y+z+w}{4}\ge\frac{\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{zw}}{2}\ge\sqrt[4]{xyzw}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you just explain in further detail what you did here? I am quite new to proofs and more specifically inequality proofs involving AM-GM.

Comment: @FlavioEsposito I used the $2$-variables AM-GM three times, twice to create two square roots & once more for the fourth root.

Comment: I see. So, just to make sure I got it right: You used AM-GM once for $\sqrt{xy}$, once for $\sqrt{zw}$, and then for $\sqrt[4]{xyzw}$?

Comment: Yep, that's right!

Comment: I'm just still a bit unsure how you got this: $\frac{x+y+z+w}{4}\ge\frac{\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{zw}}{2}$. Is this purely based on a logical conclusion?

Comment: For any values $a$, $b$, $x$, and $y$, if $\color{red}{a}\ge \color{red}{x}$ and $\color{blue}{b} \ge \color{blue}{y}$, then $\color{red}{a}+\color{blue}{b} \ge \color{red}{x}+\color{blue}{y}$. To see why:
$$
a \ge x \\
a+b \ge x+b \ge x+y
$$
We know that $\color{red}{\frac{x+y}{2}} \ge \color{red}{\sqrt{xy}}$ and $\color{blue}{\frac{z+w}{2}} \ge \color{blue}{\sqrt{zw}}$ by AM-GM. Apply the result above and you have that relation.